# Stomping after a table tennis serve or follow through?

Tags: technique, table-tennis, serve, follow-through

I often see a lot of veterans stomp their feet after hitting the ball.

Why would one want to stomp after hitting the ball?

Is this purely a stylistic issue? Or does it improve ones follow-through?

You can see an example [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwz_-2DchRE&feature=related).

Comment: @Kevin http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwz_-2DchRE&feature=related

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some players stomp during the serve to hide the sound of the racquet hitting the ball. The sound of the contact can often clue a receiver into the pace and spin of a serve.

Other players merely stomp as a natural motion as they try to impart spin onto the ball.

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO. By stomping people disguise the actual sound of  the actual moment the ball is served.

Comment: I agree in that it's to hide how (hard) you hit the ball to try to hide the pace and spin of the ball.

Answer (score 5):

Although I can't verify this, it could be for balance purposes. I know that in tennis (related sport), when you come into net to hit a volley, good technique states that you should "stomp" with your (assuming a right-handed player) left foot for a forehand volley and stomp with your right foot for a backhand volley because it helps you mentally and physically hit your shot with a firm wrist and be on balance like you need to be.

Comment: This is not correct, it has to do with hiding the sound of the spin...

Answer (score 0):

It is stylistic.

The fact that the people you refer to stomp **after** they hit the ball shows that it isn't improving anything. Also, research shows (I'll find it for you if I can) that your legs to not effect the way your arms move, so it won't help follow-through. It's all in your head :-)

Comment: Please try to. i'd love to read thi research you speak of.

Comment: My wife played table tennis extensively and once traveled to Europe with the US college team, I believe. She has told me that the stomp often serves to distract an opponent from reading the spin of your serve. Also I disagree that you legs do not affect your arms. Your legs and core are the platform for all upper body action. Look at the clean and jerk; It seems like your arms would lift the weight, but the momentum drive comes from the legs.